# Flask, SocketIO, and Docker net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: python, docker, flask, flask-socketio

I have a Flask app that is only ever deployed as a local service that continuously puts out this error, in the browser console, and fails to load content. The app is basically a media collection and distribution service. I understand that there is a mismatch between the content-length value in the header but I don't know where this is coming from, how to ignore it or how to fix the issue.

The error occurs in two contexts.

1. When loading the gallery view which loads files from a local folder (within the flask app).
2. When posting new media through the app's API (using Flask-SocketIO).

The errors are intermittent and never consistently on the same files.

This seems to happen more often now that I have moved the app to a Docker container with the following stack:

- python:3.7-alpine
- Flask (1.0.2)
- Google Firestore (DB)
- Flask-SocketIO
- Gunicorn
- Eventlet
- (There are a bunch more packages I'm using but I don't think they are all relevant to the issue)

This is running on Windows 10 in a Docker container and all media locations are mounted as volumes using the -v Docker command.

I also seem to get a stream of BlockingIO errors but I'm not sure they are related to the issue.

Comment: I should also note that when I run this using `flask run`, I do not get this error.